# How can a windows desktop application be installed and run from the web

Tags: windows, web, installation, msix

It is possible to run a windows desktop application from a weblink.
This can be achieved bij registering a custom protocol.
Something like this (myapp.reg):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myapp]
@="\"URL: myapp protocol\""
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myapp\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myapp\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myapp\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\myapp.exe\" -URL \"%1\""
```

The URL: “myapp://parameters" will start the myapp application.

Is there a way to install the application and custom protocol, when it is not installed jet, before running the application?

Could this be done with msix?

By replacing the URL with: “ms-appinstaller:?source=http://myaddres/myapp_1.0.0_x64__z3ppzndyktgh8.msix”

The simplified flow (without user interaction/cancellation) would be:

```
if not installed myapp then
   install myapp 
else if not up to date myapp then
  update myapp
run myapp with parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible using the MSIX and AppInstaller support. The full details are in [this Microsoft blog post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/passing-installation-parameters-to-a-windows-application-with/ba-p/1719829), but here is a short extras from the article:

> The way MSIX supports this feature is by leveraging protocol support. Your app must register a **custom protocol**, which will be used to launch the application after it has been installed from your website using App Installer.

> Then, your application will retrieve all the information about the activation through the startup arguments, like in a regular protocol activation scenario. For example, let's say you register a protocol called ***contoso-expenses:***. This means that, when someone invokes a URL like ***contoso-expenses:?source=campaign***, your application will receive as activation arguments the value source=campaign. This is exactly what App Installer is going to do the first time it launches your MSIX packaged app after the installation has been completed.

Comment: thx, this works partly. 
First I have more than one parameter, something like contoso-expenses:?source=campaign&destination=target. This does not work. 
Second if de custom protocol is already installed the installer still starts.